# emplace and unordered_map<?, std::array<?, N>>

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map, stdarray, emplace

I have a `std::unordered_map<string, std::array<int, 2>>`. What is the syntax of `emplace`ing a value into the map?

```
unordered_map<string, array<int, 2>> contig_sizes;
string key{"key"};
array<int, 2> value{1, 2};

// OK ---1
contig_sizes.emplace(key, value);

// OK --- 2
contig_sizes.emplace(key, std::array<int, 2>{1, 2});

// compile error --3
//contig_sizes.emplace(key, {{1,2}});

// OK --4 (Nathan Oliver)
// Very inefficient results in two!!! extra copy c'tor
contig_sizes.insert({key, {1,2}});

// OK --5
// One extra move c'tor followed by one extra copy c'tor
contig_sizes.insert({key, std::array<int, 2>{1,2}});

// OK --6 
// Two extra move constructors
contig_sizes.insert(pair<const string, array<int, 2>>{key, array<int, 2>{1, 2}});
```

I am using `clang++ -c  -x c++ -std=c++14` and clang 3.6.0

I tested the code in http://ideone.com/pp72yR

Addendum:
(4) was suggested by Nathan Oliver in the answer below

Comment: `emplace` needs to deduce the type of its arguments, but `{{1,2}}` has no type (it's not an expression).

Answer (score 5):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) [`std::unordered_map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) is declared as

```
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace( Args&&... args );
```

So it tries to deduce the types passed to it.  This brings into play [temp.deduct.type] § 14.8.2.5

> — A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list (8.5.4) but the parameter does not have a type for which deduction from an initializer list is specified (14.8.2.1). [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> void g(T);  
> g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> —end example ]

So no type is able to be deduced.

If you want to create objects on the fly then you would use the form:

```
contig_sizes.emplace(key, std::array<int, 2>{1, 2});
```

Or we can create a `typedef`

```
typedef pair<const string, array<my_class, 2>> pair_type;
```

And then we can have

```
contig_sizes.emplace(pair_type{key, {1, 2}});
```

You could also use [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) which takes a `pair` of the key/value which can be constructed from a braced initializer list.

```
contig_sizes.insert({key, {1, 2}});
```

Comment: `unordered_map::insert` results in two extra copy c'tors (http://ideone.com/pp72yR). To reduce it down to only move c'tors, you seem to need this horrible syntax: `contig_sizes.insert(pair<const string, array<int, 2>>{key, array<int, 2>{1, 2}});`

Comment: @LeoGoodstadt That can be solved with a simple `typedef` though.  `typedef pair<const string, array<my_class, 2>> pair_type;` and then `contig_sizes.insert(pair_type{key, {1, 2}});`

Comment: @LeoGoodstadt I updated the answer to show a easy on the eyes `emplace()` use.

Comment: I can't get it to remove the extra copy c'tor with the `typedef`.  For some reason, I still need `contig_sizes.emplace(pair_type{key, std::array<my_class, 2>{1, 2}});`. :-( And that is still not as efficient as my original `contig_sizes.emplace(key, std::array<int, 2>{1, 2});`!!! I might as well `typedef` the value type: `typedef std::array<int, 2>{1, 2} value_type;` `contig_sizes.emplace(key, value_type{1,2});`

Comment: @LeoGoodstadt did you try `contig_sizes.emplace(pair_type{key, {1, 2}});`?

Comment: Yes. Extra copy c'tor. See (http://ideone.com/pp72yR) ("Emplace with pair typedef"). This may be because `key` is a lvalue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93074/discussion-between-leo-goodstadt-and-nathanoliver).